# Smooth rotation to target with separate yaw, pitch and roll smooth times

Tags: unity, camera, rotation, quaternion, easing

I'm trying to write a camera script in Unity that would smoothly rotate the camera over time towards the desired rotation, with separate input parameters for yaw, pitch and roll smoothing, and I can't figure out how to do it properly. That camera would be meant to follow a vehicle that can move and rotate in 3D space. I've tried many things, most recently the code below:

```
Vector3 targetLookDirection = (lookTarget - cameraPosition).normalized;
Quaternion targetCameraRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetLookDirection, vehicleTransform.up);

Vector3 currentDeviation = (transform.rotation * Quaternion.Inverse(targetRotation)).eulerAngles;
//since deviation * target = current, then deviation = current * inv(target)
Vector3 newDeviation = new Vector3
{
    x = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currentDeviation.x, 0f, ref pitchVelocity, pitchSmoothTime),
    y = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currentDeviation.y, 0f, ref yawVelocity, yawSmoothTime),
    z = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(currentDeviation.z, 0f, ref rollVelocity, rollSmoothTime)
};
transform.rotation = targetRotation;
transform.Rotate(newDeviation);
```

where `lookTarget` and `cameraPosition` are Vector3s, and `transform` refers to the camera transform since the script is attached to the camera Game Object. The code is in `LateUpdate()`.

The code looks logical to me, but in reality when I run it with the `Smooth Times` set to around 0.25 the camera just shakes chaotically. The shaking behaviour is also different depending on which way I look in 3D space (with visibly different behaviour when looking towards z+ direction), which is weird to me since the smoothing is only working with relative rotation of the camera from the target rotation, and not their world rotations.

I would very much appreciate it if you could let me know how to fix this script to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem. I changed the last two lines of the code.

Instead of:

```
transform.rotation = targetRotation;
transform.Rotate(newDeviation);
```

I wrote:

```
Quaternion newDeviationQuat = Quaternion.Euler(newDeviation);
transform.rotation = newDeviationQuat * targetRotation;
```

And now it works perfectly.
Don't ask me why.

Answer (score 0):

Quaternions are hard. Usually to avoid gimbal lock and to make life easier I would advice to split up the camera arm. So one transform is doing x and z rotation while the other transform, its child, is doing y in local space.

I can recommend the asset DoTween, there is a free version, it makes interpolation quite easy you could just say `transform.DoLookAt` and say how long it should take as an argument. DoTween can also just rotate on one axis.

Comment: DoTween sounds like an interesting option, for now I used the Cinemachine Transposer body algorithm which contains an option to smoothly rotate camera with separate pitch, yaw and roll smoothing, and I managed to fix my problem by putting my script on a Cinemachine virtual camera and integrating it with the Transposer smoothing algorithm. When I have time I'll try digging into Cinemachine source code to figure out how it does it so I could put similar logic in my camera script and make it work without relying on Cinemachine.